# Embed iframe in my facebook fan page

Tags: facebook, iframe, tabs

I have an image that i want to make a welcome message on my facebook fan page. How can i do this? I have been 10 days searching the internet but with no hope

thanks a million in advance

Answer (score 1):

Page Tab application is what you'll need. Here's a great walk-thru/tutorial on them:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/